# can't install psycopg2 in windows

Tags: python, django, pip, pycharm, psycopg2

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, to
kenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tcmjfuu0\psycopg2_9679e782c5f144bdbc57c64ce0e24caf\setup.py'"'"'; **file**
='"'"'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tcmjfuu0\psycopg2_9679e782c5f144bdbc57c64ce0e24caf\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'ope
n'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-iw5_prz4\install-reco
rd.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Include\psycopg2' Check the logs for full command output.

I tried,
pip install psycopg2
pip install psycopg2- binary

pip install pipwin
pipwin install psycopg2

pip3 install psycopg2

python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install psycopg2

py -m pip install "psycopg2

Comment: It is not clear from the above (because it is really difficult to read) what the exact problem is. Try using a proper Python script rather than running it all from the command line. Also, please explain what the problem is trying to install the *psycopg2* package.